# 'within few next days' OR 'within next few days'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence-patterns

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct? and why?

> The project will be completed within next few days.

OR

> The project will be completed within few next days.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but the most English solution sounds "within a few days." The context makes it clear that you talk about the *next* days. Especially the*within* part.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both expressions don't sound *English*. I would go with:

> The project will be completed *within a few days*.

So without the *next*. Since you say *will be*, it implies the action will take place in the future.

Alternatively you could say:

> The project will be completed *within **the** next few days*.

So with a *the*.